# `Unable to find class` error in Drools

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I'm trying to define a very simple function in `Drools` as below:

```
import java.util.List;

function int sumLengths(List<String> strings) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (String s : strings)
        counter += s.length();
    return counter;
}
```

but it gives me error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [ function sumLengths (line:5):
Unable to resolve type List<String> while building function. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to find class 'List<String>' ]
```

any idea?

Comment: add tag java or jboss. so I can filter out your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps it is an issue with generics ([This](http://osdir.com/ml/java.drools.user/2008-02/msg00024.html) points me to that conclusion). Have you tried the following (or similar):

```
function int sumLengths(List strings) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (Object s : strings)
        counter += ((String) s).length();
    return counter;
}
```

If it doesn't work you could use this instead:

```
function int sumLengths(String[] strings) {
    int counter = 0;
    int length = (strings != null) ? strings.length : -1;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < length; ++idx) {
        counter += strings[idx].length();
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which one was it? (I didn't use drools yet).

Comment: the first one did. I didn't try the second one :)

Comment: This is old, but I found that when I tried to pass in an Array of Strings as in the second example, Drools kept on thinking it was a list and I'd get errors like: The method sumLengths(String[]) in the type SumLengths is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Answer (score -1):

change to

```
function Boolean consulta(celda cref, java.util.List celdas) {

......

 celda c = (celda) celdas.get(y);
}
```